# How to unravel array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to generate a `list` for `scipy.optimize.minimize`'s `boundry condition`, it should look like this:

```
bonds = [(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99),
        (0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99),
        (0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99),]
```

I'm wondering if there is any elegant way of doing it?

I tried:

```
bonds = [[(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99)] for i in range(3)]
```

But this generates

```
[[(0.0, 0.99), (-30, 30), (-30, 30), (0.0, 30), (0.0, 30), (-0.99, 0.99)],
 [(0.0, 0.99), (-30, 30), (-30, 30), (0.0, 30), (0.0, 30), (-0.99, 0.99)],
 [(0.0, 0.99), (-30, 30), (-30, 30), (0.0, 30), (0.0, 30), (-0.99, 0.99)]]
```

How can I remove the inner `[]`, to `unravel` the inner arrays into a single one? Or is there any other good way of doing it?

Comment: Not necessarily what you may want, but a [reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) for ways to flatten a list of lists.

Comment: @Reti43, thanks, that's another way of thinking this problem. I just didn't think about `flat` at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do:

```
bonds = [(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99)] * 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`[i for sublist in bonds for i in sublist]`

Comment: Please add some supporting text for this code snippet. Explain why it would solve the OP's problem. Help others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Other way, using [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from `itertools` module:

```
>>> l = [(0.0, 0.99), (-30, 30), (-30, 30), (0.0, 30), (0.0, 30), (-0.99, 0.99)]
>>> bonds = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l*3))
>>> bonds
[0.0, 0.99, -30, 30, -30, 30, 0.0, 30, 0.0, 30, -0.99, 0.99, 0.0, 0.99, -30, 30, -30, 30, 0.0, 30, 0.0, 30, -0.99, 0.99, 0.0, 0.99, -30, 30, -30, 30, 0.0, 30, 0.0, 30, -0.99, 0.99]
```

**EDIT**: Comparing the speed of some expression, I've tried the following:

```
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'l = [(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99)]' 'bonds=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l*3))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.95 usec per loop
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'l = [(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99)]' 'bonds = l*3'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.147 usec per loop
$ python3 -mtimeit -s 'l = [(0., 0.99),(-30, 30),(-30, 30),(0., 30),(0., 30),(-0.99, 0.99)]' 'bonds=list(itertools.chain(l*3))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.859 usec per loop
```

As one can notice, `bonds = l*3` is the fastest among the above expressions.